# How to use % method with conditional opeator in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

I am currently learning DS in python. I was creating class for stack.
I had couple of questions-

1. What type of coding skills is required for me to be an expert in Data Structures in python? Is it using the in-built structures of python or creating the basic data structures like stack, queue, linked lists, graphs etc.?
2. How can I check whether the elements of a list are integer or not so that I can pop them?

   ```
   class Stack():
   def __init__(self):
       self.items = []

   def isEmpty(self):
       return self.items == []

   def push(self, item):
       self.items.append(item)

   def pop(self):
       return self.items.pop()

   def peek(self):
       return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

   def size(self):
       return len(self.items)

   def show(self):
       return self.items
   lt = ['a', '1', '2', 'b', '3']
   a = Stack()
   for i in lt:
      a.push(i)
   for j in lt:
      if not j.isdigit():
         a.pop()
   a.show()
   ```

how can I use the if statement here so that all the non-integer items can be popped from the list?
the `if j!=%d` is throwing an error

Comment: This question will get better reception if entirely removing #1 and (only) focusing on the actual issue in #2. There are no “special” coding skills required.

Comment: Data structures transcend programming languages.  Almost every language has arrays, lists, queues, stacks, maps/dicts, and so on.  You need to learn those CONCEPTS so you know how and when to apply them to your problems, regardless of languages.  There is no such thing as "an expert in Data Structures in Python".

Comment: When removing a set of things, it's almost always better to build a new list with the items you want to keep.  `lst = [i for i in ['a','1','2','b','3'] if not i.isdigit()]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `pop` from `a`, since you didn't add anything to it.  Here's how you'd write that as a loop:

```
lst = ['a','1','2','b','3']
a = []
for i in lst:
    if not i.isdigit():
        a.push(i)
```

Better is the list comprehension I cited in the comments:

```
lst = ['a','1','2','b','3']
a = [i for i in lst if not i.isdigit()]
```

Note that you should not name your own variables `list`, since that hides the Python built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Question No 1:**
in-built structures of python is not a solution to understand data structure. so if you want really improve your skill on data structure and algorithm then defiantly do it manually. and under stand core concept how stack, link list, queue different type of sorting works. after clear concept understand BFS , DFS, shortest path find out algorithm and also different type of algorithm. You will achieved the knowledge about time complexity and space complexity of algorithm. so don't go built in structure if you have know idea about data structure and algorithm.

**Answer Question No 2:**

```
class Stack():
  def __init__(self):
      self.items = []

  def isEmpty(self):
      return self.items == []

  def push(self, item):
      self.items.append(item)

  def pop(self):
      return self.items.pop()

  def peek(self):
      return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

  def size(self):
      return len(self.items)

  def show(self):
      return self.items
lt = ['a', '1', '2', 'b', '3']
a = Stack()

for j in lt:
   if not j.isdigit():
      a.push(j)
a.show()
```